# What does "soufflé in a windstorm" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> Which leads to the third, and possibly most slippery, personality quirk required to do lexicography: the ability to quietly to the same task on the same book until the universe collapses on in itself **like a soufflé in a windstorm**.

What does "soufflé in a windstorm" mean here?

Comment: What do you know about soufflés? Do you understand what a windstorm is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [simile](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-similes.html), as opposed to being idiomatic.

A [souffle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/souffl%C3%A9) is well known for being a very delicate dessert, so delicate that the slightest breath of wind can deflate it.

A [wind storm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/windstorm) (as the name suggests) is far more than a slight breath of wind and would certainly delate (or collapse) a souffle with ease.

The author is essentially comparing the collape of the universe to the collapes of something very delicate in heavy wind.

Another example:

> Which leads to the third, and possibly most slippery, personality quirk required to do lexicography: the ability to quietly to the same task on the same book until the universe collapses on in itself like a house of cards under a tidal wave.

Comment: I don't think it's a very well-chosen simile for the context, but I'd say it could be at least *slightly* improved by substituting ***while*** for ***until*** - alluding more strongly to the lexicographer's tenacity in sticking to his task ***regardless of external turmoil***, rather than ***until the end of time***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- there is no "while" in the whole sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingersI was just following the style of the original simile but I do think the author intended to use until. When the end of time happens, the author will do lexicography. Although I think there was potentially an error - "ability to quietly **do** the same task"